# How to do the equivalent of a lateral join in MySQL 5.7?

Tags: mysql, greatest-n-per-group, mysql-5.7

I'm trying to get the informations from two tables, one table that contains general data about an object A, and B holding the history of supplementary data for this object.

What i want to do is get all the records from A And the corresponding lastest instance of B (highest id) with a fast request, the two tables being quite big. B has a key that allows it to identify which A it is linked to since it is a one to many relation.
I also want to get infos if there are some from a third table C, i can get those info from two fields that are present in B. There also can be no C data for a given B, i want to know that too..

From what i seached on the forums, lateral join seems to be the solution, but it does not exist in my version of MySQL.

I also want to be able to filter query with variable conditions in A and B column values.

What i'm trying right now (functionnal if i can wait hours) is:

```
SELECT a.*, b.*, c.* 
FROM a
    INNER JOIN (SELECT b.* FROM b ORDER BY b.id DESC) b ON b.a_id = a.id
    LEFT JOIN c ON c.val1 = b.val1 AND c.val2 = b.val2
GROUP BY b.id
```

Comment: Do you have a sample of how you want to use `LATERAL`?

Comment: The `ORDER BY` in your example is meaningless; the `ORDER BY` can be ignored.  (However, it may not be -- and this may be the cause of slowness.)

Comment: The order by is used in order for the group by to group by the latest entry of B, because ther are many b rows for one a row, and i want the latest b row per a row

Comment: In that case, shouldn't there be a `LIMIT 1`?

Comment: This question is common on Stack Overflow, usually under the tag [tag:greatest-n-per-group]. Have you tried any of the suggested solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What your describing is something that window functions like ROW_NUMBER() help with but those too are MySQL 8+. With MySQL 5.7 things are a little trickier but there are a couple of ways to do it.

```
SET @rank := 0;
SET @aid := 0;

SELECT
  a.*, b.*, c.*
FROM
  a
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT
      @rank := CASE WHEN b.a_id = @aid THEN @rank + 1 ELSE 1 END AS RankedRow
      ,b.*
      ,@aid := b.a_id
    FROM
      b
    ORDER BY
      b.a_id
      ,b.id DESC
) AS b
  ON a.id = b.a_id
  AND b.RankedRow = 1
LEFT JOIN c
  ON c.val1 = b.val1
  AND c.val2 = b.val2
```

This uses a variable to hold the current row number and uses a trick to update that value as well as return it. If a_id is the same, it's incremented by 1 but when a_id changes, it is reset to 1.

Another option is to join b to itself

```
SELECT
  a.*, b.*, c.*
FROM
  a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT
    b.*
  FROM
    b
  LEFT JOIN b AS newerb
    ON newerb.a_id = b.a_id
    AND newerb.id > b.id
  WHERE
    newerb.id IS NULL
) AS b
  ON a.id = b.a_id
LEFT JOIN c
  ON c.val1 = b.val1
  AND c.val2 = b.val2
```

Here newerb will be null if there is no id greater than b for the same a_id and therefore must be the latest row.

I've used both solutions in the past, I tend to prefer the latter as it's more readable but it may be slower depending on how much data you have.

I haven't time to test both examples so apologies in advance for any typos I've missed.

Comment: It works but it is way too slow, on little datasets, the fetch of C table is much faster, but on bigger ones, even when i remove the c table left, join, it will run for an undefined amount of time (stopped after 1 hour, supposed to take less than 5 secs), with my method (which i obviously know it's not great) if i remove the c table left join, it runs like 2 secs then done, but i know it'll also not work on a db with the restriction on order by and group by (which i can't disable on my provider) Do you have a fast solution ?

Comment: You may want to know that my a table has 50k+ records, b 70k+ and c 30k+

Comment: I tested now your first solution (fixed the typos in it to make it work) and it works fine.... if i remove the join with c, and it has another (major) problem, there are duplicates a.ids, it does not group as it should. Do you have a fix for this ?

Comment: @LightFox7 It would help if you could post some sample so that I and anyone else looking to help and get a better idea of what you're working with along with what query you're now working with. Your tables aren't particularly large so you shouldn't be hitting performance issues unless there's something else about the data that isn't yet apparent.

Comment: @LightFox7 I'd also make sure that you have a single index including b.a_id and b.id in that order. And then also on the columns in b and c that you are joining c with

Comment: @LightFox7 Apologies just spotted the issue with the first solution, I'd omitted the setting of the aid variable which must happen AFTER it's been compared. It should work better now.

Comment: I made your solution work with a few little tricks (in some case couldn't set aid and rankedrow before doing the request) but now it's good, many thanks.